# How to implement Cannon's algorithm in Go using channels?

Tags: algorithm, go, matrix, channel

I am implementing [Cannon's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon%27s_algorithm) in go using channels, but channels synchronisation makes it sequential. How to achieve concurrency to make it faster?

```
package algorithms

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type matrixType [][]int

var mu sync.Mutex

type matrixResult struct {
    Label  string
    Matrix matrixType
}

func CannnEntry2(a, b matrixType) matrixType {
    A := matrixType{
        {2, 3, 4, 5},
        {9, 8, 7, 6},
        {5, 4, 2, 3},
        {8, 7, 3, 4},
    }

    B := matrixType{
        {3, 5, 7, 6},
        {2, 7, 6, 3},
        {7, 5, 3, 2},
        {4, 3, 2, 5},
    }

    row := len(A)

    matrixA := initialAlignmentA(A, row)
    matrixB := initialAligmentB(B, row)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Create a channel to receive results
    resultCh := make(chan matrixResult, row)

    // Iterate through the steps and spawn goroutines
    for i := 0; i < row; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go multiplyConcurrent(matrixA, matrixB, i, resultCh, &wg)
        matrixA = alignHorizontalByOne(matrixA, 1)
        matrixB = alignVerticalByOne(matrixB, 1)
    }

    // wg.Wait()

    // Close the channel after all goroutines finish
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resultCh)
    }()

    // Collect results from the channel
    var resultMatrices []matrixResult

    for result := range resultCh {
        resultMatrices = append(resultMatrices, result)
    }

    // Add all the result matrices
    finalResult := assembleResult(resultMatrices...)
    fmt.Println("Final Result: ", finalResult)
    return finalResult

}
```

NOTE: some of the help functions are redacted here
this is my code. when I executed this code with larger matrix, it took more time compare to normal matrix multiplication code

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: It would be relevant to see what's being done inside `multiplyConcurrent`. Can you share the whole thing?